# Derivation under the sign of the integral (Lebesgue integral) using existence of bounded partial derivative

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, derivatives, lebesgue-integral

Let $f(x, y)$ be measurable function of two variables: $a < x < b$, $c < y < d < \infty$,
such that there exists partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$
which is bounded on $x\in (a, b)$, $y\in (c, d)$.
And $\int_{[c, d]}|f(x, y)|dy < \infty$ for some $x\in (a, b)$.

Prove that

1. $\int_{[c, d]}f(x, y)dy < \infty$ for any $x\in (a, b)$.
2. We can "derive under the sign of the integral":
   $$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\int_{[c, d]}f(x, y)dy = \int_{[c, d]}\frac{\partial f(x, y)}{\partial x}dy$$
   for $x\in (a, b)$.

I will be glad for any idea, comment, hint or advice.

P.S. I have some doubts about that. Probably it is not true at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $y$, $t \longmapsto f(t,y)$ is differentiable with uniformly bounded (in $t,y$) derivative so that $|f(t,y)| \leq C|t-x|+|f(x,y)|$ (where $C$ is the uniform bound on the derivative and $x$ is given above), so that $\int_c^d{|f(t,y)|\,dy} <\infty$ for any $t$.

Now set $a < t < b$ and let $h \neq 0$ be small. Then $\frac{1}{h}\left(\int_c^d{f(t+h,y)\,dy}-\int_c^d{f(t,y)\,dy}\right)=\int_c^d{\frac{f(t+h,y)-f(t,y)}{h}\,dy}$. But the integrand is always at most $C$ for any $h,y$, yet it converges pointwise to $\partial_1f(t,y)$ as $h$ goes to $0$.

Therefore, by dominated convergence, the integral converges to $\int_c^d{\partial_1f(t,y)}$, QED.

Comment: Thank you for answer! How did you get the first proposition? I mean $|f(t,y)| \leq C|t-x|+|f(x,y)|$. How did you get that? I assume using this representation $f(x)=f(x_{0})+f'(x_{0})(x-x_{0})+o(x-x_{0})$ but why we didn't manage $o(x-x_{0})$ part?

Comment: No, that’s just the mean value theorem ( https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem).

Comment: Thank you! I think I get the main idea of the proof. But I have one more question. Why $\frac{f(t+h,y)-f(t,y)}{h}\leq C$? I know that the its limit (derivative) bounded by C but I still can't understand why it is true for $\frac{f(t+h,y)-f(t,y)}{h}$? Or we can replace C with some another positive number?

Comment: No, it’s really the *mean value theorem* with $C$. Read the wikipedia link!

Comment: It is clear now. Thank you very much!